# iOS App Store localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, localizable.strings

I've been searching for a way to localize an App Store link. At a certain moment i alert the user with the option the write a review and for the english version i use the following code, which works ok.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/EnglishWordsforKids"]];
```

But if i localize the app name in chinese "小孩儿英语单词", what should the link be?

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/小孩儿英语单词"]];
```

Is this the correct path to my app on the Chinese App Store ?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same link (the first one in your example), because technically it's the same app. Since the link opens the App Store app on the device it will display whichever App Store the current user is logged into.

Hence if the user has a Chinese Apple ID, and your app is translated in iTunes Connect, it will pull the Chinese translation. If it's a US account it will display the English translation. If it's an account with a language into which you have not translated the app yet, it will display the base translation (usually English).